# Live CD with no GUI, with root autologin and autostart my console script

Tags: boot, command-line, autostart, auto-login

I need to create linux Live CD with latest kernel with next functions -

1. it must boot without any questions (language, menu, etc)
2. It must boot without GUI, only console and better with nomodeset
3. It must autologin
4. It must autorun my script

So i've donloaded Ubuntu 18.10 iso, put my script in it. I've found an article about systemd.unit=multi-user.target, so I can boot without GUI.
Please help me to resolve #1,3 and 4.
Thanks!
Sorry for stupid questions, i'm new with linux. And English :)

Comment: I've found autologin solution for console: Copy "/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service" to "/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/ getty@tty1.service" and change "ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM" to "ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a my-user-name --noclear %I".